# require from variable content instead of a file

Tags: php

Normally I write cache files with a content like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title><?= $foo; ?></title>
</head>
<body>
<p><?= $content; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I write the cache file:

```
<?php

file_put_contents('cache_file.php', $aboveContent);
```

Then I `require` them like:

```
<?php

require 'cache_file.php';
```

But now if I can't write the cache file (for example no write privileges on the dir where the file should be written to or no caching needed e.x. in development) then I like to require the variable content (which holds the file content for the cache file) directly.

Is that somehow possible? I didn't find a way to achieve that. Or should I write to the temp dir of PHP and require from there again?

Comment: If you don't have write privileges for the filesystem for your cache files, then use something like memcache or redis

Comment: Okay to clarify that: there probably shouldn't be a caching mechanism (e.x. during development)...

Comment: What do you mean `require the variable content`? Like `echo $cacheVariableWithContent;`?

Comment: Yes exactly like echo it but execute the PHP code in the `$cacheVariableWithContent;`

Comment: You'll want `eval` then

Comment: `eval` = evil... I try to don't use `eval`.

Comment: I don't think `eval()` will allow the literal code, it executes PHP code.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER It's no more evil than writing to a file and requiring the file. They both execute dynamically-generated code. If the code is created by the script, not user-generated data, it's not very evil.

Comment: Can't you just check if the cache file exists and only use it when it does?. You can use the variable content otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Assign to a variable and echo it:

```
$content = <<<EOF
<html>
<head>
<title>$foo</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>$content</p>
</body>
</html>
EOF;

echo $content;
```

Comment: Thx for your answer :-). But then the two variables `$foo` and `$content` don't get replaced.

Comment: But when I write this content to a file and require it the variables don't get replaced. I need the `<?= $var; ?>` then. So with your solution I would need two different versions one with PHP tags and one without.

Comment: This is instead of writing to a file. That's what the question asked for.

Comment: If you can't write to the normal cache file directory, couldn't you use `/tmp` instead? That should always be writable.

Comment: Yes if the caching is not possible... but if the caching is possible there should be a code which works for both out of the variable and out of the file. So which covers both cases. But I guess there's no such thing... that was what I was asking for. Exactly that's my solution right now... I liked to know if there is another possbility without writing to `/tmp` but then I'll do it like that.